# How do you isolate a subapplication from the main site on IIS7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

**Senario:**

I'm running IIS7 on Win Server 2008 Web Edition

I have a MVC application at the route of the website (main app)

The website HOST is domain.com

I've created a virtual application /testapp with has an ASP.Net application (sub app)

**Problem:**

when I navigate to http://domain.com the main app works as expected but when I navigate to http://domain.com/testapp the sub app seems to be running but processing the main app web.config.

Some of the errors I was getting involved missing dlls that only the main app required - this could be solved by copying the dlls into the sub app bin folder but isn't an ideal solution.

**Question:**

I don't think this is an MVC/ASP.Net issue but instead an ISS7 one. How do I configure IIS7 so that these two application don't interfere with each other?

Answer (score 2):

This problem is by design due to inheritance of web.config files. You have a couple of solutions:

1. Move the site elements at the root of the site into a application subfolder that sits side by side with your other application and remove as much of the parent's web.config as possible.
2. Copy all the elements in the parent web.config to the child web.config that are needed and use the `location` elements to block inheritance in the child:

> ```
> < location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false" >
>     < system.web >
>     ...
>     </ system.web >
> </ location >
> ```

Comment: option #2 doesn't seem to work as I've added it but parent web.config is still being processed.

Comment: option #1 is not good, for me, because it means my site will be reachable at mydomain.com but only at mydomain/com/app.

Comment: @DamienMcGivern - The parent web.config will *always* be processed because of inheritance. The only way to make option #2 work is to mitigate any conflicting tags at the parent web.config.

Comment: @IdoRan - If the MVC app is in a virtual app, then obviously mydomain.com will go to the root and not the MVC app baring a redirect at the root.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem when I've add custom modules in my ASP MVC 4 application running on IIS7.
I've found a solution by simply removing and adding the module as so:

```
 <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="GlobalizationModule"/>
      <add name="GlobalizationModule" type="GlobalizationHttpModule, MyWebSite"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

It is specific solution to this problem, hope it helps.

Ido.